# How to avoid undefined index

Tags: php

How can you easily avoid getting this error/notice in PHP?

```
Notice: Undefined index: test in /var/www/page.php on line 21
```

The code:

```
$table = 'test';
$preset = array();
method($preset[$table]);
```

The array `$preset` exists but not with the specified index

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index/16971723#16971723 for IMHO a much better answer I gave in this question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if it exists using [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists):

```
$table = 'test';
$preset = array();
if(array_key_exists($table, $preset)) {
    method($preset[$table]);
}else{
    // $table doesn't exist in $preset
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/isset):

```
$table = 'test';
$preset = array();
if(isset($preset[$table])) {
    method($preset[$table]);
}else{
    // $table doesn't exist in $preset
}
```

Comment: + 1 on this,  isset() does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a NULL value, while array_key_exists() does.

Answer (score 3):

Use `if (isset($preset[$table]))`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can check first if key exists by using isset().

```
if ( isset($preset[$table]) )
```

Return true if exists, otherwise return false.